# have PDF form, need to port to website

Tags: php, html, pdf

So here is what I have: a PDF form (job application) that a client is requesting to put on their website as a form and the data gets sent to them when an applicant on the site fills the form out. My idea is as follows: dissecting the PDF, taking its fields and making the HTML form, then processing on the server side, creating the new PDF and emailing as an attachment to the client. However, something tells me that there is a better, more effective way of doing it. Is that so?

Comment: How about building the form by hand in HTML, and sending the results through E-Mail? Doing this as a PDF programmatically as you describe is possible, but an *awfully* bothersome lot of work.

Comment: There are free scripts that create pdf's.. pdf is a open fileformat so it's not that bothersome ;P

Comment: I agree with Pekka...taking the final step and creating a PDF with the form response seems like overkill. (unless of course it's a specific project requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client specifically asks for a pdf sent by mail in return then no there is no better way :P If they do not have any certain specifications then perhaps storing the pdf applications in a database where they can retreive them by themself through a webpage is a better idea. You could still notify them by email that a new application have been received. This way they can organize new applications better, because lets face it.. management always makes a mess out of their mailbox.

Comment: @Jonas: "...storing the pdf applications in a database..." - could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You store the data submitted by users in a database. Your client can then connect to an administrative side of your site. There you'd have a script that can list the applications, and a button to download them. The button triggers a script which builds the PDF with that application's data embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the form to FillAnyPdf.com and get a code snippet to embed the form directly on the website.  Or you can save the form on fillanypdf.com and link to it from their website.  The company can be notified by email every time the form has been filled out.  There are some limitations but this can also be setup in just a few minutes.